# Energy estimate of grid function

Tags: boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

Consider a grid function $v$ defined on
$$
\Omega_h:=\{x_i:0\leq i\leq m\}
$$
where $x_i=a+ih$, $h=\frac{b-a}{m}$.There are three types of norms
$$
||v||=\sqrt{h\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}v_i^2}
$$
$$
||v||_{\infty}=\mathop{max}\limits_{0 \leq i\leq m}|v_i|
$$
$$
|v|_1=\sqrt{h\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\delta_xv_{i-\frac{1}{2}})^2}
$$
where $\delta_xv_{i-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{v_i-v_{i-1}}{h}$.
I am trying to prove that if $v_0=0$ and $v_m$ takes arbitrary values, then
$$
||v||_{\infty}\leq\sqrt{b-a}|v|_1,\quad||v||\leq\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{2}}|v|_1.
$$
And if $v_0$ and $v_m$ take arbitrary values then
$$
(\max_{0\leq i\leq m}|u_i|)^2\leq2\max\{u_0^2,u_m^2\}+\frac{b-a}{2}|u|_1^2
$$
I have known the case when $v_0=v_m=0$:
$$
v_i=\sum_{j=1}^i(v_j-v_{j-1})=h\sum_{j=1}^i\delta_xv_{j-\frac{1}{2}}
$$
$$
v_i=-\sum_{j=i+1}^m(v_j-v_{j-1})=-h\sum_{j=i+1}^m\delta_xv_{j-\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
Then applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives
$$
|v_i|^2\leq(x_i-a)[h\sum_{j=1}^i\delta_xv_{j-\frac{1}{2}}]^2
$$
$$
|v_i|^2\leq(b-x_i)[h\sum_{j=i+1}^m\delta_xv_{j-\frac{1}{2}}]^2.
$$
Then
$$
(b-a)|v_i|^2\leq(b-x_i)(x_i-a)|v|_1^2\leq\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}|v|_1^2.
$$
The rest of the proof is simple.
But I can't figure it out in the case when $v_0$ and $v_m$ take arbitrary values rather than 0.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am a little surprised that the $\infty$ and $1$ - norm include $0, m$, while the energy/$2$-norm does not.

Comment: I am not sure if you can actually show these claims if $v_0 = v_m \neq 0$. Consider the case that $v_i $ is constant, but non-zero. Then both $\Vert v \Vert_\infty $ and $\Vert v \Vert$ will be nonzero, while $\Vert v \Vert_1$ will be identically zero.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't make it clear and I re-edit my problem. There are 3 circumstances actually. I am not trying to prove the same thing when v0 and vm are nonzero.